# MongoDB $ne in sub documents

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53692eb238ed04c824679f18"),
    "firstUserId" : 1,
    "secondUserId" : 17,
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5369338997b964b81d579fc6"),
            "read" : true,
            "dateTime" : 1399403401,
            "message" : "d",
            "userId" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("536933c797b964b81d579fc7"),
            "read" : false,
            "dateTime" : 1399403463,
            "message" : "asdf",
            "userId" : 17
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to select all documents that have firstUserId = 1 and also have sub documents
that have userId differnet ($ne) to 1 and read = false.
I tried:

```
db.usermessages.find({firstUserId: 1, "messages.userId": {$ne: 1}, "messages.read": false})
```

But it returns empty cause messages have both 1 and 17.
And also how to count subdocuments that have given case?

Comment: Have you tried the $elemMatch operator? Since its in an array, it might help to do that: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch
I haven't tested, but I would think it would look something like:
     db.usermessages.find({firstUserId: 1, "messages": {$elemMatch: {"userId": {$ne: 1}, "read": false}}})

Comment: db.usermessages.find({firstUserId: 1, messages: {$elemMatch: {userId: {$ne: 1}, read: false}}}) seems to do the trick, thank you, now how to count subdocuments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the count of all the documents which are returned after your match criteria? If Yes, then you might consider using aggregation framework. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/

Something like below could be done to get you the counts:

```
db.usermessages.aggregate(
  { "$unwind": "$messages" },
  { "$match": 
     { "firstUserId": 1, 
       "messages.userId": { "$ne" : 1}, 
       "messages.read": false 
     }
  },
  { "$group": { "_id" :null, "count" : { "$sum": 1 } } }
)
```

Hope this helps.

PS: I have not tried this on my system.